# Insert filename in external-command

Tags: external-command

I'm using Latex a lot lately and I find myself having to leave vim so I can execute the command `pdflatex *filename*` too often (compile the code and create a pdf file).

I'd like to make a command `command! Latex execute "pdflatex %"` something like that to be able to compile the code directly from vim but I don't know how to expand the filename since "pdflatex %" is a string and the terminal understands it as so.

How could I have the filename expand to what I want?

Comment: So you want `pdflatex *filename*` to run on your shell, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expand()` is what you need.

```
command! Latex execute "!pdflatex " . expand('%')
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks. If I wanted though, every time I executed the command, to save the file first how could I do it?

Comment: That would be: `command! Latex execute ":w | !pdflatex " . expand('%')`

Comment: I just found out it doesn't work if the file name contains a black space. The compiler interprets it as two different files. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try wrapping `expand('%')` inside `shellescape(expand('%'))`

Comment: @Wylex `command! Latex execute "!pdflatex %` should work, you don't need the `expand()` here since `:!` already does that. The command in your question *is* missing a `!` though.